# How to compare DateTime by day?

Tags: java, junit, jodatime

I want to compare two `DateTime` Joda objects, to find out if the datetime is on the same day or not.

Therefore I'm using a `DateTimeComparator` configured to compare from year to day only (so no time comparison).

But the following test succeeds, even though it should fail. Why?

```
@Test
public void validateDayNotEqual() {
    DateTimeComparator.getInstance(DateTimeFieldType.year(), DateTimeFieldType.dayOfWeek())
    DateTime lastTimestamp = DateTime.now().minusDays(1);
    assertTrue(comparator.compare(DateTime.now(), lastTimestamp) == 0);
}
```

Comment: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeComparator.html#getDateOnlyInstance%28%29

Comment: Great, would you add this as a comment? It works as I'd expected.

Comment: @membersound I've posted an answer about the reason it doesn't work. Please consider viewing it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the javadoc of `DateTimeComparator`:

```
public static DateTimeComparator getInstance(DateTimeFieldType lowerLimit,
                                             DateTimeFieldType upperLimit)
Returns a DateTimeComparator with a lower and upper limit. Fields of a magnitude less than the lower limit are excluded from comparisons. Fields of a magnitude greater than or equal to the upper limit are also excluded from comparisons. Either limit may be specified as null, which indicates an unbounded limit.

Parameters:
    lowerLimit - inclusive lower limit for fields to be compared, null means no limit
    upperLimit - exclusive upper limit for fields to be compared, null means no limit

Returns:
    a comparator over all fields between the limits
```

As you can see, the real problem was that you swapped the two arguments, the `lowerLimit` and the `upperLimit`. Since the `upperLimit` is exclusive but it can be omitted, it should be changed to:

```
    DateTimeComparator comparator = DateTimeComparator.getInstance(DateTimeFieldType.dayOfMonth());
```

...or this would also work fine (and perhaps more elegant):

```
    DateTimeComparator comparator = getDateOnlyInstance();
```

**EDIT 2**: The answer had contained serious errors and were subsequently corrected.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. That is really counter-intuitive and will probably help others too.

Comment: @membersound If it was helpful, please check the 'v' button under the vote-down button to mark this answer as accepted :)